# How to anchor a wpf data grid which is inside a stack panel a fixed distance from the main window's four corners

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, stackpanel

I have the following wpf layout given to me by my employer. It makes use of multiple nested stack panels.
I'm trying to anchor a data grid which is inside a stack panel a fixed distance away from the main window's four corners. And whenever the grid contains data of which some of it is hidden because of the parent window's size, it is supposed to display scroll bars which must disappear if not needed.

---

I set the data grid's and the stack panel's width to Auto so that it  fills the width and that makes the horizontal and vertical scroll    bars behave as i want them to. BUT the grid doesn't have the required    height.

---

But when i try to set the data grid's height property to auto both the horizontal and vertical scroll bars disappear resulting in hidden data.
I tried setting the data grids height property to a fixed size and updating it whenever the window is resized but the scroll bars are still hidden how can i fix this?

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="441" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Name="stackPanel1">
            <ListBox Height="100" Name="listBox1" Width="253" />
            <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="256" Click="button1_Click" />
            <StackPanel Name="stackPanel2">
                <StackPanel Height="34" Name="stackPanel3" Width="249" />
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" Height="282" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="502" Width="525" StateChanged="Window_StateChanged">
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <my:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl11" Loaded="userControl11_Loaded" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Please provide the Xaml for the layout you currently have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand all this StackPanel inside StackPanel stuff. You should simply use Grid for your layout:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Height="100" Name="listBox1" Width="253" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="256" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Height="34" Name="stackPanel3" Width="249" />
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" />
</Grid>
```

And having an empty StackPanel `stackPanel3` as spaceholder seems awkward. Thats what WPF elements have a [Margin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx) property for.

Answer (score 3):

When you put items into a vertical `StackPanel` they like to pretend they have infinite vertical space. Switch over to specifying rows on your `Grid`, and place your `DataGrid` in one of those rows. When it's inside a `Grid` it knows how much space it has available and should show the scrollbars appropriately.